# So I'm having trouble understanding files in C++

Tags: c++, file, append, binaryfiles

I just started learning files and I understand how to set it up and get it to work. I have to write this program where I have to allow the user to enter some information and have the user also update and adjust any data, using binary.
So I can write up until the point where the user can write to and read from the file. But I don't know how to let the user adjust data or add data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class client {
public:
  string name;
  int balance;
  string id;

};

int main()
{
   int ans;
   int x;
   string nameIn;
   string adjName;
   client client1;
   ofstream out("client1.dat", ios::binary);

   cout << "\nDo you want to add information or update info" << endl;
   cin >> ans;
   if (ans == 1)
   {
     cout << "\nPlease enter the name of your client" << endl;
     cin >> nameIn;
     x = nameIn.length();
     if (x <= 10)
    {
        for (int i; i < 10; i++)
        {
            adjName[i] = nameIn[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = x; i < 10; i++)
        {
            adjName[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    client1.name = adjName;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the balance of your client" << endl;
    cin >> client1.balance;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the id of your client" << endl;
    cin >> client1.id;

    cout << "\nThe name of your client is " << endl << client1.name
        << endl << "\nThe balance of your client is " << endl
        << client1.balance << endl << "\nThe id of your client is "
        << endl << client1.id;

    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&client1), sizeof(client));

}
/*

else if (ans == 2)
{
    string answer, newName,line;
    cout << "\nWhat name do you want to update? " << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "\nWhat is the new name?" << endl;
    cin >> newName;

    if (out)


}
*/
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

so the name needs to be only 10 characters long, so that we can adjust/update it. It compiles and runs, but every time the compiler gets to the part where it checks the name length, it freaks out and says "debug assertion failed"
string subscript out of range.

Also a thing about this code-- if i run it without the bits where you adjust the name to a certain array length, the program runs, and stores everything nicely. But when I try to read back the .dat, it reads it back but exits with an access violation, forcing me to manually stop the debugging. What am I doing wrong?

this is the code for reading the file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class client {
public:
 string name;
 int balance;
 string id;
};

int main()
{
  client client1;
  char ans;
  cout << "\nDo you want to view the information about your client?"
     << endl;
  cin >> ans;
  ifstream in("client1.dat", ios::binary);

  if (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
  {
      in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&client1), sizeof(client));
      cout << "The name is " << endl << client1.name << endl
          << "The balance is " << endl << client1.balance << endl
          << "The id is " << endl << client1.id << endl;
 }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can't serialize non POD types like `std::string` to a binary file. `std::string` internally holds a pointer to the data on the heap, which can't be restored from reading it back from the file.

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify. POD? I'm still a beginner and am kind of lost with files. Does this have something to do with reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This code is too long and complicated for the problem you're trying to solve. When writing code you should develop new functionality in isolation, and when asking for help you should post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You seem to be asking about several bugs; pick one and prepare code that attempts to do *that one thing*, and if it doesn't work, show us that.

Comment: **P**lain **O**ld **D**ata type.

Comment: _"Does this have something to do with reinterpret_cast"_ Yes.

Comment: So how do I use strings with binary? How does reinterpret_cast resolve this problem?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` does not resolve the problem. It makes it worse by hiding the error. Casts mean "Compiler, I'm about to do something that looks really stupid, but I know what I'm doing and it's not." So unless you really do know what you are doing and it really isn't stupid, don't use them. In this case, rather than writing the `client` class to the file, you need to write the members of the class to the file individually.

Comment: The string is tricky because you need to tell the reader where the string ends. Common solutions are to write the length of the string to the file before writing the string data or placing a sentinel value after the string just like NULL terminating a good ol' c-style string. With the numbers [you need to make sure endian is respected.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) If you are reading and writing on the same computer architecture that's not going to be a problem, but you should read up on it so it doesn't get you later.

Comment: But everywhere I look it tells me to use reinterpret_cast. That's literally the only way I know how to write to a binary file. How would I go about writing each member individually.

Comment: Also quick question-- how do you write the length of the string to the file before writing the string data?

Comment: @JackFaber What you are looking for is called de-/serialization. There are non standard libraries that support this, like e.g. `boost::serialization` or google protocol buffers.

Comment: @JackFaber _"But everywhere I look it tells me to use reinterpret_cast."_ Certainly not with `std::string`, it might work for fixed size character arrays like  `char name;[50]`.

Answer (score 1):

As for the 1st part:

```
 for (int i; i < 10; i++)
       // ^
```

misses to initialize `i` to zero. Also what if the input was smaller than 10 characters? You're going to access the `std::string` out of bounds. You should replace the `if`/`else` and loops with simply

```
 adjName = nameIn;
 while(adjName.length() <= 10) {
     adjName += ' ';
 }
```

to get rid of the debug assertion.

---

For the 2nd part of the question, as already mentioned in the comments you cannot do this with a structure containing classes like `std::string`.

The `reinterpret_cast<char*> (&client1)` just obfuscates that `std::string` uses a pointer to the dynamically allocated character data internally, and that cannot be restored meaningfully when reading the stored data back later (hence the access violation you get).

A viable way might be to use something like

```
struct client {
    char name[11];
    int balance;
    char id[5];
};
```

As I guess you need to do this for a homework exercise, and for this purpose that would probably be sufficient.

But you quickly can see the drawbacks, that the character data needs to be fixed in size and you cannot have arbitrary length strings. I never would use such for production ready code.

Another pitfall (as also mentioned) is, that `int` isn't represented in the same way (order of bytes used, i.e. endianess) in the same way for different CPU architectures. So the binary file can't be used portably with different computers.

---

The simplest solution is not to use a binary file, but a text formatted file and overload the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const client&)` and `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, client&)` output/input operators.

Or use some 3rd party library like `boost::serialization` or google protocol buffers, that supports de-/serialization to binary files.

Comment: okay so i was following your instructions and this is where i got to

Comment: @JackFaber Fine, if you think that answer was helpful and solved your problems consider accepting it by clicking the big white checkmark at the left side :-) ...

Comment: I couldn't post the code here so i posted it as an answer- could you please look over it. thanks

Comment: @JackFaber That's not an answer, but follow up questions likely. Post another question instead please. Also you didn't follow my instructions actually.

Comment: @JackFaber You missed that `std::string` characters can't be accessed arbitrarily without having the `std::string` initialized at a proper length. That's why I advised to write that `while` loop exactly as shown in my example.