# String in binary files, struct?

Tags: c++, struct, binaryfiles

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct client {
public:
char name[10];
  int balance;
  char id[5];

};

int main()
{
  int ans;
 int x;
 string nameIn;
 string adjName;

 ofstream out("client1.dat", ios::binary);

 cout << "\nDo you want to add information or update info" << endl;
 cin >> ans;
 if (ans == 1)
 {
    cout << "\nPlease enter the name of your client" << endl;
    cin >> nameIn;

  while (nameIn.length() <=10)
  {
      for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         adjName[i] = nameIn[i];
     }
 }
 while (10-adjName.length()>0)
{
    int x = 10 - adjName.length();

    for (x; x< 10; x++)
    {
        adjName[x] = ' ';
    }
}
 for (int i = 0; i < adjName.length(); i++)
{
    client name = adjName[i];
}
```

but this part keeps showing up as an error

```
 for (int i = 0; i < adjName.length(); i++)
   {
    client name = adjName[i];
```

I'm trying to let the user write a name where if it is longer than 10 letters, it will cut it off, or shorter it will add blank spaces. 
Also can someone please explain why you cannot write strings to binary files please?
And why do I have to use struct rather than class, if I'm using string.

Comment: try to be precise where the error is and what the error is. also this could be infinite loop:   while (nameIn.length() <=10)

Comment: client name = adjName[i]; for this line it says-- no suitable constructor exists to convert from char to "client"

Comment: @JackFaber *Also can someone please explain why you cannot write strings to binary files please?*  -- Inspect the file you created when you tried to write the string.  Do you see your string in that mess of data?   Then that's evidence by inspection.  You can't turn the junk you see in the file back into the original string.  So the real question to ask is "what did I save?"

Comment: FYI: The way SO works you will need to post 2 questions: One about the the longer than 10 character problem, and another about how to write strings to a binary file.  Once someone solves the first question, be sure to accept their answer and ask the next one separately.

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?  If not, get one.  Your understanding will increase 10-fold once you can step through this line-by-line and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo in your code: `client name = adjName[i];` makes no sense. Did you forget the dot?

Second (and most importantly) you are using C character pointers in C++ code. You should not unless you have to - and right now there is no need. Your code should look something like following:

```
struct client {
   std::string name;
};

// read the data
name = nameIn.substr(0, 10);
```

Comment: _"write a name where if it is longer than 10 letters, it will cut it off"_ will need at least an array of  `char name[11];` to include the terminating `'\0'` character. And I've already tried coping with that user before in their previous question. They're pretty resistant to understand what we try to tell them. I've been giving up actually, and don't see any more value for future research.

Comment: _"You should not unless you have to"_ Have a look at their [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002805/so-im-having-trouble-understanding-files-in-c/34004058?noredirect=1#comment55768679_34004058) and why I was advising so. In that context it may make sense and be perfectly valid.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, serialization, eh? alright, though I am not fan of identity-encoding when serializing.

Comment: They've been asking for binary files originally. I'm also not a fan of that, but just wanted to point you at the overall context, since I've been there already. I don't say your answer is wrong by any means.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thanks - I love to have context, and at least I see what is happening.